# Is is possible to select the value of a object in a array regardless of the object name? (reduce-method) (beginner)

Tags: javascript

i am experimenting with the the reduce-method in javascript and was curious if its possible to write a more universal code?

```
function total(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce(function cb(sum, n) {return sum + n.x;}, 0);
};

console.log(total([{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}]));
```

Output: 6

If if change one x to y:

```
function total(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce(function cb(sum, n) {return sum + n.x;}, 0);
};

console.log(total([{x: 1}, {y: 2}, {x: 3}]));
```

Output: NaN

My first question would be why? Why its not sum up the values of all object named x. So the Output should be: 4

My second and more important question: It is possible to write my function this way, that it will sum up the value of all objects in the array regardless of the Objectname? So that in my second function the Output will be always six, regardsless if input [{x: 1}, {y: 2}, {z: 3}]. Because its "annoying" that i have to "know"  all the names of the object to sum it up, before i write the function and cant use it for any kind of array with this structure....

Comment: _"Output: NaN

My first question would be why?"_ Because `1 + undefined + 3` is `NaN`

Comment: `return sum + Object.values(n)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Output: NaN My first question would be why?"* Because `1 + undefined + 3` is `NaN`:

```js
console.log(1 + undefined + 3)
```

You can return the first value of each object:

```js
function total(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce((sum, n) => sum + Object.values(n)[0], 0);
};

console.log(total([{x: 1}, {y: 2}, {x: 3}]));
```

If an object can have multiple properties and you want the sum of all of them you can sum up all values:

```js
function total(arr1) {
    return arr1.reduce((sum, n) => sum + Object.values(n).reduce((sum, n) => sum + n), 0);
};

console.log(total([{x: 1}, {x: 5, y: 2}, {x: 3}]));
```